# How to read data written to a file from one android application using another android application

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I used following method to write data to a file in one android application

```
 private void writeFileToInternalStorage() {

    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    BufferedWriter writer = null;

 try{
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myFile.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE|MODE_WORLD_READABLE)));
      writer.write("Hello world!");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
      if (writer != null) 
      {
        try 
        {
            writer.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to read that file from another android application using this method

```
 private void readFileFromInternalStorage(){
    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try 
    {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("myFile1.txt")));
         String line;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            buffer.append(line + eol);


        }

       TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);  
        tv.setText(buffer.toString().trim());

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (input != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                input.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second method can't read the file. I added read write permissions also, but it shows only blank screen. What can be the error and how can I correct that ??. I'm new to Android programming and need your help.

Thanks!

Comment: This two methods are working properly if both methods are in one application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
openFileOutput("myFile.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE|MODE_WORLD_READABLE))
```

The documentation says:

> This file is written to a path relative to your app within the

**So the case is you are writing file in path relative to application 1 and trying to read it from
path relative to application 2.**

You should be able to call Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the root path to the SD card and use that to create a FileOutputStream. From there, just use the standard java.io routines.

**Look below snippet to write file to SD card.**

```
private void writeToSDCard() {


try
        {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "filename");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            writer.write("Hello World");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**Look below snippet to read file saved on SD card.**

```
private void readFileFromSDCard() {
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    // Assumes that a file article.rss is available on the SD card
    File file = new File(directory + "/article.rss");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("File not found");
    }
    Log.e("Testing", "Starting to read");
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where to add that ?? I have no such knowledge in Android programming. I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: call write function onClick of a button in application 1 and call read function onClick of a button in application 2.

Comment: include <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in manifest of application 1

Comment: I have tested the method that to read a file, but it shows force close message why is that??

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to place it into the scdcard into something like `/sdcard/Android/data/package/shared/`